# Filesystem metadata

Tags: filesystems, terminology

When someone talks about filesystem metadata in the context of a linux/unix filesystem, does that includes directories? I mean is a directory operation considered a metadata change?

And implementation related data (like block pointers in the inode structures, inode bitmaps, etc.), are they part of filesystem metadata?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, directory is not considered as metadata. Actually it is managed as a file.
Filesystem metadata includes some bitmaps, and block group descriptors, etc. But it can vary depending on the type of filesystems

Comment: Also ownerships, timestamps, permissions.